# iOS mail client dosent like img links

Tags: ios, email, hyperlink, uiactionsheet

Just created a email template, but any img which is wrapped in a anchor tag just brings up the share action sheet when clicked (text links are fine) I have no idea what is going on, I have also seen a few others ask about this issue with no real resolve for it, dose anyone have any idea whats causing it? Or a fix? Thanks!

Example of code...

```
<a href="http://www.destination.com">
<img src="imageurl" />
</a>
```

Comment: I believe you may be interested to edit your question, because it sounds like unrelated to the programming (which is stack overflow for).

Comment: are you sending your email with the proper headers? Why is this tagged with uiactionsheet?

Answer (score 0):

In what e-mail client did you open the mail?
Maybe try not to link to the image directly, but link to a HTML page that contains the image (`<img>`)

Comment: iOS apple mail client, also happends in gmail on iOS aswell, but not on Yahoo! aparently, seems more like an iOS

I am not linking to the actual image, but to a web page FROM that image, I have added code example